# Will LINQ to SQL Pick Up Trigger Changes/Errors?

Tags: .net, sql, sql-server-2005, linq-to-sql, triggers

I'm not very knowledgeable about the scope of certain SQL operations and how they relate to LINQ to SQL. If I have a trigger that updates a field in a record after it is inserted, what happens when I insert a new record using LINQ to SQL? So given this order of operations:

1. Create new "MyObject" instance.
2. Assign MyObject properties.
3. Insert record using LINQ to SQL.
4. SQL Insert Trigger Updates a property of that record to a new value.

Would step 5 be:

1. "MyObject" holds the updated value.

   or
2. "MyObject" holds the original value that I assigned to it.

And another question given the same steps 1-3:

4.. SQL Trigger throws an error and rolls back the Insert, similar to [this](http://www.java2s.com/Code/SQLServer/Transact-SQL/CreatingaTriggerandraiseanerror.htm) example.

Would step 5 be:

1. LINQ to SQL throws a SQL Exception.

   or
2. ???

Comment: Is there some reason you don't test this yourself? This would be fairly trivial to set up.

Comment: Testing would *help* understand the scope of each operation, but won't leave me with a clear answer of when each step happens, or if the results are even consistent.

Answer (score 0):

Answers: 2 and 1

But it's certainly worth testing as well because the exception may depend on connection string params.